# GDI+ error in c# web service while saving image on sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2

hi i make a web services that will store the image  in inetpub\wwwroot\finder in this folder ... so in this case is it necessary to make a virtual directory....
I get the following error ---

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
           at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at Service.add_product(String addprod)

even if allowing Everyone's all permissions allow of my finder folder...

```
   string img_base64;
   [WebMethod]
   public string add_product(string addprod)
   {

       String[] str_arr = addprod.Split('>');
       city = str_arr[0];
       cat = str_arr[1];
       description = str_arr[2];
       prod_pos = str_arr[3];
       _mobile = str_arr[4];

       img_base64 = str_arr[5];

       lati = str_arr[6];
       longi = str_arr[7];
       land = str_arr[8];

       Decimal latitu = Convert.ToDecimal(lati);
       Decimal longit = Convert.ToDecimal(longi);
     //  Environment.CurrentDirectory();
      // Environment.GetFolderPath("~");
       string saveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" +_mobile+ ".jpeg");

       byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img_base64);
       Image image;
       using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
       {
               image = Image.FromStream(ms);
               image.Save(saveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
       }

       String img_path = "http://Server IP/folder name/" + _mobile + ".png";
       string sql = "insert into add_product (city,category,description,prod_pos,mobile,latitudeimage,longitude,landmark,image) values('" + city + "','" + cat + "','" + description + "','" + prod_pos + "','" + _mobile + "','" + latitu + "','" + longit + "','" + land + "','" + img_path + "')";
       con.InsertData(sql);

       return "Added Successfully";
   }
```

Please suggest the solution.....

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath("~")` gives you the directory, so you need to include a filename when you save the file.

```
string saveLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "filename.png");
```

With that being said, I would reconsider saving to the IIS folder.  You would be better suited storing items like these to your AppData directory on the machine.